# Pandas dataframe: grouping by unique identifier, checking conditions, and applying 1/0 to new column if condition is met/not met

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataset pertaining customer churn, where every customer has an unique identifier (encoded key). The dataset is a timeseries, where every customer has one row for every month they have been a customer, so both the date and customer-identifier column naturally contains duplicates. What I am trying to do is to add a new column (called 'churn') and set the column to 0 or 1 based on if it is that specific customer's last month as a customer or not.

I have tried numerous methods to do this, but each and every one fails, either do to tracebacks or they just don't work as intended. It should be noted that I am very new to both python and pandas, so please explain things like I'm five (lol).

I have tried using pandas groupby to group rows by the unique customer keys, and then checking conditions:

```
df2 = df2.groupby('customerid').assign(churn = [1 if date==max(date) else 0 for date in df2['date']])
```

which gives tracebacks because dataframegroupby object has no attribute assign.

I have also tried the following:

```
df2.sort_values(['date']).groupby('customerid').loc[df['date'] == max('date'), 'churn'] = 1
df2.sort_values(['date']).groupby('customerid').loc[df['date'] != max('date'), 'churn'] = 0
```

which gives a similar traceback, but due to the attribute loc

I have also tried using numpy methods, like the following:

```
df2['churn'] = df2.groupby(['customerid']).np.where(df2['date'] == max('date'), 1, 0)
```

which again gives tracebacks due to the dataframegroupby

and:

```
df2['churn'] = np.where((df2['date']==df2['date'].max()), 1, df2['churn'])
```

which does not give tracebacks, but does not work as intended, i.e. it applies 1 to the churn column for the max date for all rows, instead of the max date for the specific customerid - which in retrospect is completely understandable since customerid is not specified anywhere.

Any help/tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `max` for return maximal values per groups and compare with `date` column, last set `1,0` values by mask:

```
mask = df2['date'].eq(df2.groupby('customerid')['date'].transform('max'))
df2['churn'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
```

---

```
df2['churn'] = mask.astype(int)
```